# Display multiple rows into column into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is my table have 2 column with 5 record. How to show these 5 record in temp table in 2.5 rows. means fetch 2 rows from this table and insert 1 rows of temp table with 4 column in stored procedure

[image]

second image is temp table how i want data. if in future i want to display 10 record in 3 rows then there will be 3.1 rows in temp table

[image]

Table name `Party_Details`

```
PID       PartyName     Address 
------------------------------------
1           Shadab      Bareilly
2           Akbar       Moradabad
3           Aqib        Bareilly
4           Majid       Moradabad
5           Shaan       Bareilly
```

Above table has 5 rows.

How to show it in 2.5 rows in temp table in a SQL Server stored procedure?

@GeorgeJoseph

If there I have show them in 1 there will be 10 column in temp table like

```
PartyName1,Address1,PartyName2,Address2............. PartyName5,Address5
```

Comment: Please post text data instead of images. It makes life easier to create a test case and debug

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i m Using MS SQL

Comment: Table Name - **Party_Details**

**PID PartyName Address**
1         Shadab  Bareilly
2         Akbar  Moradabad
3         Aqib          Bareilly
4           Majid  Moradabad
5         Shaan  Bareilly

above table have 5 record.

Now how to show it in 2.5 rows in temp table in MS SQL stored procedure.
@GeorgeJoseph

if there i have show them in 1 there will be 10 column in temp table like PartyName1,Address1,PartyName2,Address2............. PartyName5,Address5

Comment: If i understand you correct, you are looking to pivot the results of the query you have now into columns.?

Answer (score 0):

```
 create procedure SP_Party_Details 
 as
 begin
 declare @id int
 set @id=(select COUNT(*) from Party_Details)

 DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    PID int primary key identity(1,1),
    PartyName varchar(20),
    Address varchar(50),
    PartyName1 varchar(20),
    Address1 varchar(50));

 DECLARE @I INT=(select Min(PId) from Party_Details);
 START:               

 If @I%2!=0
      insert into @tempTable(PartyName,Address) select p.PartyName, p.Address from Party_Details p where p.PId=@I
    else    
      update t set t.PartyName1=(select PartyName from Party_Details where PId=@I),
    t.Address1=(select Address from Party_Details where PId=@I) from @tempTable t where t.PId=(select max(pid) from @tempTable)

 SET @I+=1;
 IF @I<=@id GOTO START; 


 SELECT * FROM @tempTable;
 end

 exec SP_Party_Details
```

[Got Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XgZU.png)

Comment: thank you so much... it is very help full.. thank you so much.. May Allah Bless u.

Comment: if temp table have 6 column (PartyName,Address,PartyName1,Address1,PartyName2,Address3) what procedure query will execute. @sri

Comment: @sri_harsha please tell me.

 if temp table have 6 column (PartyName,Address,PartyName1,Address1,PartyName2,Address3) what procedure query will execute.

Answer (score 0):

**For 6 columns**

```
create procedure [dbo].[SP_Party_Details_Three_Step]
as
begin
declare @id int
set @id=(select COUNT(*) from Party_Details)

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    PID int primary key identity(1,1),
    PartyName varchar(20),
    Address varchar(50),
    PartyName1 varchar(20),
    Address1 varchar(50),
    PartyName2 varchar(20),
    Address2 varchar(50));

DECLARE @I INT=(select Min(PId) from Party_Details);
START:             

If((select Count(*) from @tempTable where PartyName2 is null)=0)
    insert into @tempTable(PartyName,Address) select p.PartyName, p.Address from Party_Details p where p.PId=@I

    else if((select Count(*) from @tempTable where PartyName1 is null)>0)
    update t set t.PartyName1=(select PartyName from Party_Details where PId=@I),
    t.Address1=(select Address from Party_Details where PId=@I) from @tempTable t where t.PId=(select max(pid) from @tempTable)     

    else
    update t set t.PartyName2=(select PartyName from Party_Details where PId=@I),
    t.Address2=(select Address from Party_Details where PId=@I) from @tempTable t where t.PId=(select max(pid) from @tempTable)

  PRINT @I;
  SET @I+=1;
IF @I<=@id GOTO START; 


SELECT * FROM @tempTable;
end

exec [SP_Party_Details_Three_Step]
```